# Help me understand a phrase from the "Java concurrency in practice"

Tags: java

On a page twelve of "Java concurrency in practice" there is a phrase

> "A good specification defines invariants constraining an object's
>   state and post - conditions describing the effect of its operation."

More or less I undersand the phrase untill the word `"post"`, then it becomes a garbage.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps the spacing is confusing. The last part of the sentence should read "post-conditions describing the effect of its operation", or what must be true about the state of the object following the completion of a method call (or any other code block).

[Post-conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-condition), along with [preconditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition) and [invariants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_%28computer_science%29), are frequently used in [design by contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). Having a formal specification does help in understanding concurrency and the side-effects of a method call. It's also useful in establishing test code and assertions.

Comment: If you're right and this should read as `post-conditions`, thank you very much!

Comment: Also thanks for helping me to understand a meaning of post-conditions.